# Non-continuous values as inputs to recurrent neural network?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am hoping to use a recurrent neural network to perform time series predictions.

Some of my inputs are between 0 and 1, while others can be > 1.

My goal is to analyze stock market trends (*please* do not lecture me on this...this is only an example). Here are some of my inputs:

1. Price change % from opening (>= 0)
2. Slope (decrease/increase) of stock in last n minutes (>= 0).
3. Whether stock is likely at one of its peaks for the day (0 to 1).

As you can see, some of the inputs are not between 0 and 1.

Can a recurrent network receive non-continuous numeric values (> 1) as input? If so, would I just pass values that are > 1 in as inputs?

Comment: My small experience in ANN area tells me that if your inputs don't represent absolute values, then you don't have to normalize. Price change, slope, peak likelyhood are all relative values, that are generally allowed to range at the same levels for every stock. If you would like to use price value, then you would have to normalize in order to teach your network patterns "reusable" between different stocks.

Comment: Good point about relative vs. absolute values. I think that makes sense. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Do you already know what will be the architecture of your network?

Comment: Three output nodes...one for likeliness of whether it's good to sell, a second for whether it's good to buy, and a third for the possible next price. Then, probably a dozen input nodes. As for hidden nodes...I am not sure...maybe between 2 and 12. Does that answer your question?

Comment: How will you compute the output of each of your neuron? Do you plan on using a sigmoid function as activation function? 
If yes, then your only problem is the order of magnitude that you will have for your input layer. See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/ the Should I standardize the input variables